# Prove $\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ is continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove $f(z)=\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ is continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

I was considering two approaches. First,
$$f(z)=\frac{\bar{z}}{z}=\frac{x-yi}{x+yi}=\frac{(x-yi)^2}{(x+yi)(x-yi)}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}i$$
By showing the real and imaginary partss are continuous we proved $f$ is continuous. But it involves a lot of calculation :(

Or we could use the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument, like $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists \delta>0$, whenever $|z-z_0|<\delta$, we have
$$\left|f(z)-f(z_0)\right|=\left|\frac{\bar{z}}{z}-\frac{\bar{z_0}}{z_0}\right|=\left|\frac{\bar{z}z_0-z\bar{z_0}}{zz_0}\right|=\frac{|\bar{z}z_0-z\bar{z_0}|}{|zz_0|}\leq\frac{|\bar{z}z_0|+|z\bar{z_0}|}{|zz_0|} =\frac{2|z|\cdot|z_0|}{|z|\cdot|z_0|}=2$$
Not correct :(

Any help?

Comment: Just use polar cordinates.  That makes it trivial.

Comment: Or you could just note that it's the quotient of two continuous, nonvanishing functions.

Comment: @fleablood If I use the polar form, $\frac{\bar{z}}{z}=\frac{r e^{-i\phi}}{re^{i\phi}}=e^{-2i\phi}$, should I say continuous with respect to $\phi$ or $z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|f(z)-f(z_0)\right|=\left|\frac{\bar{z}}{z}-\frac{\bar{z_0}}{z_0}\right|=\left|\frac{\bar{z}z_0-z\bar{z_0}}{zz_0}\right|=\frac{|\bar{z}z_0-\bar{z}z+\bar{z}z-z\bar{z_0}|}{|zz_0|}=\frac{|\bar{z}(z_0-z)+z(\bar{z}-\bar{z_0})|}{|zz_0|}\le \frac{|\bar{z}(z_0-z)|}{|zz_0|}+\frac{|z(\bar{z}-\bar{z_0})|}{|zz_0|} $$

We know, $$ |\frac{\bar{z}}{z}|=1$$ is bounded and $z_0$ is fixed. Hence proved.

Comment: One step farther, $| \bar z / z | = 1$ and $|z_0-z|=|\bar z- \bar z_0|$ so the last expression is in fact $2 |z-z_0| / |z_0|\,$.

Comment: $$ |\frac{\bar{z}}{z}|=|e^{-2i\theta}|.$$ right? How it is strict equality?

Comment: ok. sorry. I forget iota term. Thank you very much :) @dxiv